# Apache website not updating after restarting docker

Tags: docker

I have created an apache2 docker container

```
docker run -dit --name tecmint-web -p 8080:80 -v /home/user/website/:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ httpd:2.4
```

This is working. but if I stop this container and start again by `docker restart <container-id>`. It does not pick new html file from my `/home/user/website/`.

How can I realign these 2 directories after restarting docker?

Comment: I assume you added new html files even though you didn't mention it.
Could you try to open a shell session in your container (`docker exec -ti <container_id> sh`) and list `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/` content?

Comment: just docker.html, which I put in /home/user/website/ of my host machine

Comment: I'm assuming your browser is caching the file. Does a hard reload reflect the change?

Comment: My issue it that, if I stop the docker and change the file content in my host system docker.html file, this does not update my container docker.html.

Comment: @raju Could you answer the questions and suggestions people ask you in the comments?